# how to extract a sentence from multiple sentence using regular expression in splunk

Tags: regex, splunk

I'm trying to extract a Applicant sentence from multiple sentences using regular expression in splunk

APPLICANT: BP Exploration (Alaska) Inc., Post Office Box 196612, Anchorage, Alaska 99519
AGENT: Jennifer Collins, BP Exploration (Alaska) Inc.
LOCATION: The project site is located within Section 26, T. 11 N., R. 15 E., Umiat Meridian; USGS Quad Map Beechey Point B-3; Latitude 70.276939º N., Longitude -148.27539º W.; near Prudhoe Bay, Alaska.

Comment: What is your actual question? Is something not working as you expected? This is very vague.

Comment: i've three sentences in a paragraph, i'm trying to extract applicant sentences in  to an filed in splunk using regular expression

Comment: Add this information to the question - not in a comment. And explain what issue you're currently experiencing.

Comment: Is this all in one line? Please make this clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As per you requirement, I think you only want to retrieve values on the line that has "Applicant at the start.

the following expression will do the job.

```
APPLICANT: (?<ApplicantGroup>[\w\d()., ]+)
```

Click [here](https://regex101.com/r/cxSWMZ/2) for demo.

Since "Applicant" here will be the identifier to locate the line after it would collect the desired values. You can add special character if there are any in the regular expression.

Comment: this is working in regular expression,but i'm trying in splunk,all the values are storing individuals

Comment: Elaborate on "all the values are storing individuals" is that a requirement or an issue?

Comment: it is an issues

Comment: by storing all the values, what do you suggest by that?

Comment: got it resolved no worries,but can you explain this APPLICANT: (?<ApplicantGroup>[\w\d()., ]+)

Comment: Yeah, It's a basic regular expression which looks for "APPLICANT:" if there is a match then this part "(?<ApplicantGroup>[\w\d()., ]+)" fetches the content after "APPLICANT:" and saves that in a group to locate the string. I hope this clarifies your questions.